# Pairing up elements from a list given a predicate

Tags: haskell

I'm relatively new to Haskell and found a challenge to create a set of tuples which greedily takes from a list given a predicate. For example, using `(\x -> \y -> odd(x+y))` on `[2,3,4,5,6,7]` could return `[(2,3),(3,2),(4,5),(5,4),(6,7),(7,6)]` or `[(2,7),(6,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,6),(7,2)]` or any other valid set of pairings, as long as it's one where each pair is symmetrical, and all items from the set are included in one and only one pairing. A key part of my challenge is to learn to work with monads, specifically Maybe/Just/Nothing, so my current function is `Eq a => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe [(a,a)]` where `Nothing` is returned if a list of tuples including every element cannot be made; for example running `(\x -> \y -> even(x+y))` on `[2,3,4,5,6,7]` would return `Nothing`, as you can't pair up all the elements to fit that predicate without leaving some out.

To start off, I thought I could generate a full list of possible pairs and filter them with the predicate. My function at present is `test p xs = filter (uncurry p) [(x,y) | (x:ys) <- tails xs, y <- ys]`, with the idea that later on I can remove tuples with duplicate first values (perhaps somehow using `nubBy`?), run `swap` from `Data.Tuple` on what's left in my list to make my pairs symmetrical, and then run a final check to see if all the elements from the list have been included so I know whether to return nothing. I realise, however, that there's probably a better way of going about this that performs fewer redundant actions and does the final check for returning Nothing earlier on. I've tried to play around with list comprehension, but I can't come up with anything serviceable.

Comment: So it should always pick the "next" one that matches?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem theoretically no, it could form the matches in any way, I just can't think of any way of doing it besides taking the next available number every time

Comment: well the problem is that right now it looks rather "underterministic". As in each input can map to several outputs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, I think that's the idea, any valid output is okay as long as my function finds one of them

Comment: There's little reason to use `Maybe` here. What significant difference is there between `Nothing` and `Just []` in this case?

Comment: @chepner that's just as more of a practice exercise for myself to learn to work with them rather than because it's strictly necessary

Comment: It would be better to find an exercise that needs `Maybe`, then.

Comment: @chepner I'll simplify this one for myself by eliminating `Maybe` in the implementation then, but regardless that's not the bit I'm struggling with

Comment: `filter (uncurry p) [(x,y) | (x:ys) <- tails xs, y <- ys] == [(x,y) | (x:ys) <- tails xs, y <- ys, p x y]`

Answer (score 2):

A tuple `(x, y)` is inherently ordered: `(x, y) != (y, x)`. It would be helpful to define an "unordered" pair type for filtering:

```
newtype Pair x = Pair { unpair :: (x, x) }

instance Eq a => Eq (Pair a) where
  (Pair p1) == (Pair p2) = p1 == p2 || p1 == swap p2
```

Then you can use a simpler method of generating sample pairs, using the `Applicative` instance for lists. You can filter out duplicates later, using `Pair`.

```
>>> (,) <$> [1, 2, 3] <*> [1, 2, 3]
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

Once you have filtered the above list, use `nub` by first converting all your initial results to `Pair` values, deduplicate using `nub`, then convert back to tuples:

```
result :: Eq x => [(x,x)] -> [(x,x)]
result = map unpair . nub . map Pair
```